# Taglib in JSP not running

Tags: java, xml, jsp, taglib

I am using netBeans and glassFish Server 4.1.1

```
<%@ taglib uri="index.html" prefix="mytag" %>  
<html>  
<body> 
    
<mytag:currentDate/>  
  
</body>  
</html>
```

And I got error like this:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 7; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1438)    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1750)  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2970)  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)  at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:298)   at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:351)   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:340)  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:254)    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:502)  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:582)    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1657)    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:185)     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)   at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1171)   at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1338)   at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspC.main(JspC.java:101)    at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle.main(JspCSingle.java:119) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:C:/Users/Queue/OneDrive/JspExE/build/web/WEB-INF/tlb.jsp(1,44) PWC6178: XML parsing error on file /WEB-INF/index.html: (line 12, col 7) org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  C:/Users/Queue/OneDrive/JspExE/build/web/WEB-INF/tlb.jsp(1,44) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:C:/Users/Queue/OneDrive/JspExE/build/web/WEB-INF/tlb.jsp(1,44) PWC6178: XML parsing error on file  C:\Users\Queue\OneDrive\JspExE\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `index.html` is a html file. You can't use HTML instead of TLD in the URI attribute of `taglib` directive.

From the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaiy.html):

> The uri attribute refers to a URI that uniquely identifies the tag
>   library descriptor (TLD), a document that describes the tag library
>   (see Tag Library Descriptors).
>
> Tag library descriptor file names must have the extension `.tld`. TLD
>   files are stored in the `WEB-INF` directory or subdirectory of the WAR
>   file, or in the `META-INF` directory or subdirectory of a tag library
>   packaged in a JAR. You can reference a TLD directly or indirectly.
>
> The following `taglib` directive directly references a TLD file name:
>
> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="tlt" uri="/WEB-INF/iterator.tld"%>
> ```
>
> This `taglib` directive uses a short logical name to indirectly
>   reference the TLD:
>
> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="tlt" uri="/tlt"%>
> ```
>
> Nested inside a `jsp-config` element is a `taglib` element, which provides
>   information on a tag library used by the pages of the application.
>   Inside the `taglib` element are the `taglib-uri` element and the
>   `taglib-location` element. The `taglib-uri` element identifies the logical
>   name of the tag library. The `taglib-location` element gives the
>   absolute location or the absolute URI of the tag library.
>
> The absolute URIs for the JSTL library are as follows:
>
> ```
> Core: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
>
> XML: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml
>
> Internationalization: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt
>
> SQL: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql
>
> Functions: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions
> ```
>
> When you reference a tag library with an absolute URI that exactly
>   matches the URI declared in the `taglib` element of the TLD (see Tag
>   Library Descriptors), you do not have to add the `taglib` element to
>   `web.xml`; the JSP container automatically locates the TLD inside the
>   JSTL library implementation. Including the Tag Library Implementation
>
> In addition to declaring the tag library, you also must make the tag
>   library implementation available to the web application. There are
>   several ways to do this. Tag library implementations can be included
>   in a WAR in an unpacked format: Tag files are packaged in the
>   `/WEB-INF/tag/` directory, and tag handler classes are packaged in the
>   `/WEB-INF/classes/` directory of the WAR. Tag libraries already packaged
>   into a JAR file are included in the `/WEB-INF/lib/` directory of the
>   WAR. Finally, an application server can load a tag library into all
>   the web applications running on the server. For example, in the
>   Application Server, the JSTL TLDs and libraries are distributed in the
>   archive `appserv-jstl.jar` in `as-install/lib/`. This library is
>   automatically loaded into the classpath of all web applications
>   running on the Application Server, so you don’t need to add it to your
>   web application.